# How to run a multithread and async loop in Web3.py to monitor the same event on multiple smart contracts?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, python, filters

I am trying to monitor similar events on different (>=2) Ethereum contracts in web3.py.

In the code below I try to monitor the Transfer event on wETH and wBTC smart contracts.

Since create filter does not allow to filter on several contracts at the same time, I want to start a process listening separately for each of the two contract and trigger the event whenever one of the filter matches the condition.

My code below creating a thread for each daemon is exiting with 0 status but works perfectly fine for one contract at a time.

What could I be doing wrong ?

```
# import the following dependencies
import json
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from web3 import Web3
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process

# add your blockchain connection information
load_dotenv()
ENDPOINT = os.getenv('ALCHEMY_URL')
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ENDPOINT))

# tokens address and abi
weth = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2')
inv = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x41d5d79431a913c4ae7d69a668ecdfe5ff9dfb68')
dai = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F')
wbtc = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599')

abi = json.loads(
    '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"delegator","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"fromDelegate","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"toDelegate","type":"address"}],"name":"DelegateChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"previousBalance","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newBalance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DelegateVotesChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"DELEGATION_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"PERMIT_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"abolishSeizing","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"addToWhitelist","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rawAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"","type":"uint32"}],"name":"checkpoints","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"fromBlock","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"uint96","name":"votes","type":"uint96"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"closeTheGates","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"delegatee","type":"address"}],"name":"delegate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"delegatee","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"delegateBySig","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"delegates","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"getCurrentVotes","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint96","name":"","type":"uint96"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"blockNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getPriorVotes","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint96","name":"","type":"uint96"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rawAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"nonces","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"numCheckpoints","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"","type":"uint32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"openTheGates","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rawAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"permit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"removeFromWhitelist","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"seizable","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rawAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"seize","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner_","type":"address"}],"name":"setOwner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tradable","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rawAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rawAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"whitelist","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]')


# define function to handle events and print to the console
def handle_event(event):
    print(Web3.toJSON(event))
    # and whatever

# asynchronous defined function to loop
# this loop sets up an event filter and is looking for new entities for the "Transfer" event
# this loop runs on a poll interval
async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for Transfer in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(Transfer)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

# when main is called
# create a filter for the latest block and look for the "Transfer" event
# run an async loop
# try to run the log_loop function above every 2 seconds
def main(contract):

    event_filter = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #try:
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(log_loop(event_filter, 2)))
    #finally:
    #    loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in [wbtc,weth]:
        contract = web3.eth.contract(address=i, abi=abi)
        #process = asyncio.ensure_future(main(contract))
        print(f'process_{i} = asyncio.ensure_future(main(contract))')
        print(contract)
        exec(f'process_{i} = asyncio.ensure_future(main(contract))')
        exec(f'process_{i}.start()')
        exec(f'process_{i}.join()')
```